# Operator ( == ) overloading error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

So, I'm working on a flowchart project(OOP), and I need to implement a condition for the GUI to let the user DrawConnector, but the "Connector" has a condition is to be drawn only when you have 2 other "Shapes" (Diamond/Rectangl/Etc.).

So this is the Connector Class.h

```
    class Connector
{
protected :
    Point start;
    Point end;
    Statement *St;
    bool DrawCondition;
    bool DelCondition;
public :
    Connector();
    virtual void setStart(Point S); //Not a condition to be virtuals
    virtual void setEnd(Point E);
    virtual void DrawConnector(Output* pOut);
    //virtual bool setDrawCondition ();
    friend bool operator == (Point P, Point T);
};
```

I actually want to "setStart" and "setEnd" by the values user "Clicks" on mouse -during runtime- and check after that if these points are to be on a shape, so it draws the connector, if not, then nothing happens.

```
void Connector::setStart(Point S)
{
    if (S == St->getPoint())
        {start = S;}
    else return;
}

void Connector::DrawConnector(Output *pOut)
{
    /*if (DrawCondition == true)*/
        pOut->DrawConnector(start.x,start.y,end.x,end.y);
}
```

You can notice I overloaded the operator " == " to check for the points if they're EVEN read ... but it ends up giving me this compilation error !

> Error 3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl operator==(struct Point,struct Point)" (??8@YA_NUPoint@@0@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall Connector::setStart(struct Point)" (?setStart@Connector@@UAEXUPoint@@@Z)   C:\Users\Cereal Killer\Downloads\Phase1-Code\Phase1-Code\Connector.obj

***EDIT***

Sorry guys, I forgot to mention I ALREADY defined the overloading in another file but I guess that was the problem, but why, isn't it a "GLOBAL FUNCTION" ?

Here's the def. :

```
bool operator == (Point P, Point T)
{
    if ( (P.x == T.x) && (P.y == T.y) )
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

One more thing, if I want to check that the given POINT is ON the SHAPE from the GUI shapes "DrawRectangle, DrawCircle, etc." How can I "trace the points that drawed the shape" ? Or is there another way ?

Comment: What does your actual definition of `==` look like?

Comment: where is definition of operator == ?

Answer (score 1):

You have declared

```
friend bool operator == ( Point P, Point T);
```

but have not defined it.

You need a definition of

```
bool operator == ( Point P, Point T) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I HAVE declared it in another file being a Global function !


[code] bool operator == (Point P, Point T)
{
 if ( (P.x == T.x) && (P.y == T.y) )
  return true;
 else return false;
} [/code]

Comment: you have to link against this file, i.e: g++ main.cpp other.cpp

Answer (score 0):

You need give a definition of the operator like any function, not just the declarations. The lack thereof will generate this error. Since it's a friend, it's just a global function, and you need to define this external to the class. Either in the header, or in the appropriate .cpp file.

```
bool operator==(Point P, Point T) {
  return P.x == T.x && P.y == T.y;
}
```

You might also consider passing the points by const reference rather than value.

Comment: I've done it in another file, that's the problem.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: @user3054349: NP. You have to link to that file then in your build settings (if you're using VS then just include the .cpp file in the solution). Or else put that function definition in your header file instead.